# Laravel Breeze - Tailwind CSS not loading on login & register page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, tailwind-css, laravel-breeze

I was trying out the Laravel Breeze authentication starter kit with Blade.

I created a new demo project and followed all the documentation steps,
but I came across the problem that Tailwind CSS is not working on my login and register pages, it only works on the laravel welcome.blade.php view.

These are the steps that I followed:

Created a new Laravel Project

> composer create-project laravel/laravel BreezeDemo

Installed the Laravel Breeze package

> composer require laravel/breeze --dev

Created all the controllers, resources etc.. for Laravel Breeze

> php artisan breeze:install

Compiled the assets

> npm install && npm run dev

I really don't get what I'm doing wrong, I've got no errors to help me, everything seems fine, and I am just following a simple installation process, I didn't even touch the code yet.

This is the welcome page:
[Welcome Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvZbF.jpg)

And this is how the login page is displayed:
[Login Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GuaK.png)

This is my welcome.blade.php page  tag (that works)

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Laravel</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <style>
        /*! normalize.css v8.0.1 | MIT License | github.com/necolas/normalize.css */html{line-height:1.15;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%}body{margin:0}a{background-color:transparent}[hidden]{display:none}html{font-family:system-ui,-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,Segoe UI,Roboto,Helvetica Neue,Arial,Noto Sans,sans-serif,Apple Color Emoji,Segoe UI Emoji,Segoe UI Symbol,Noto Color Emoji;line-height:1.5}*,:after,:before{box-sizing:border-box;border:0 solid #e2e8f0}a{color:inherit;text-decoration:inherit}svg,video{display:block;vertical-align:middle}video{max-width:100%;height:auto}.bg-white{--bg-opacity:1;background-color:#fff;background-color:rgba(255,255,255,var(--bg-opacity))}.bg-gray-100{--bg-opacity:1;background-color:#f7fafc;background-color:rgba(247,250,252,var(--bg-opacity))}.border-gray-200{--border-opacity:1;border-color:#edf2f7;border-color:rgba(237,242,247,var(--border-opacity))}.border-t{border-top-width:1px}.flex{display:flex}.grid{display:grid}.hidden{display:none}.items-center{align-items:center}.justify-center{justify-content:center}.font-semibold{font-weight:600}.h-5{height:1.25rem}.h-8{height:2rem}.h-16{height:4rem}.text-sm{font-size:.875rem}.text-lg{font-size:1.125rem}.leading-7{line-height:1.75rem}.mx-auto{margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto}.ml-1{margin-left:.25rem}.mt-2{margin-top:.5rem}.mr-2{margin-right:.5rem}.ml-2{margin-left:.5rem}.mt-4{margin-top:1rem}.ml-4{margin-left:1rem}.mt-8{margin-top:2rem}.ml-12{margin-left:3rem}.-mt-px{margin-top:-1px}.max-w-6xl{max-width:72rem}.min-h-screen{min-height:100vh}.overflow-hidden{overflow:hidden}.p-6{padding:1.5rem}.py-4{padding-top:1rem;padding-bottom:1rem}.px-6{padding-left:1.5rem;padding-right:1.5rem}.pt-8{padding-top:2rem}.fixed{position:fixed}.relative{position:relative}.top-0{top:0}.right-0{right:0}.shadow{box-shadow:0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1),0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.06)}.text-center{text-align:center}.text-gray-200{--text-opacity:1;color:#edf2f7;color:rgba(237,242,247,var(--text-opacity))}.text-gray-300{--text-opacity:1;color:#e2e8f0;color:rgba(226,232,240,var(--text-opacity))}.text-gray-400{--text-opacity:1;color:#cbd5e0;color:rgba(203,213,224,var(--text-opacity))}.text-gray-500{--text-opacity:1;color:#a0aec0;color:rgba(160,174,192,var(--text-opacity))}.text-gray-600{--text-opacity:1;color:#718096;color:rgba(113,128,150,var(--text-opacity))}.text-gray-700{--text-opacity:1;color:#4a5568;color:rgba(74,85,104,var(--text-opacity))}.text-gray-900{--text-opacity:1;color:#1a202c;color:rgba(26,32,44,var(--text-opacity))}.underline{text-decoration:underline}.antialiased{-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;-moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale}.w-5{width:1.25rem}.w-8{width:2rem}.w-auto{width:auto}.grid-cols-1{grid-template-columns:repeat(1,minmax(0,1fr))}@media (min-width:640px){.sm\:rounded-lg{border-radius:.5rem}.sm\:block{display:block}.sm\:items-center{align-items:center}.sm\:justify-start{justify-content:flex-start}.sm\:justify-between{justify-content:space-between}.sm\:h-20{height:5rem}.sm\:ml-0{margin-left:0}.sm\:px-6{padding-left:1.5rem;padding-right:1.5rem}.sm\:pt-0{padding-top:0}.sm\:text-left{text-align:left}.sm\:text-right{text-align:right}}@media (min-width:768px){.md\:border-t-0{border-top-width:0}.md\:border-l{border-left-width:1px}.md\:grid-cols-2{grid-template-columns:repeat(2,minmax(0,1fr))}}@media (min-width:1024px){.lg\:px-8{padding-left:2rem;padding-right:2rem}}@media (prefers-color-scheme:dark){.dark\:bg-gray-800{--bg-opacity:1;background-color:#2d3748;background-color:rgba(45,55,72,var(--bg-opacity))}.dark\:bg-gray-900{--bg-opacity:1;background-color:#1a202c;background-color:rgba(26,32,44,var(--bg-opacity))}.dark\:border-gray-700{--border-opacity:1;border-color:#4a5568;border-color:rgba(74,85,104,var(--border-opacity))}.dark\:text-white{--text-opacity:1;color:#fff;color:rgba(255,255,255,var(--text-opacity))}.dark\:text-gray-400{--text-opacity:1;color:#cbd5e0;color:rgba(203,213,224,var(--text-opacity))}.dark\:text-gray-500{--tw-text-opacity:1;color:#6b7280;color:rgba(107,114,128,var(--tw-text-opacity))}}
    </style>

    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

And this is my app.blade.php  tag (that doesn't work)

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap">

    <!-- Scripts -->
    @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
</head>
```

Comment: consider marking my answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

Comment: Make sure you have PHP 8 installed. @vite works with Laravel 9.x and to install Laravel 9 make sure you have PHP 8 is installed.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are missing assets on your login page try adding:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">
```

to your Login/Signup page's layout and then recompile by `npm run dev` or `npm run hot`

### Update (Nov 2022)

try to use this:

```
composer require laravel/breeze
php artisan breeze:install
npm install
npm install autoprefixer@10.4.5 --save-exact
npm run dev
```

Comment: Hi, i tried adding this in my app.blade.php but it didn't work :(

Comment: Hey, strange, can you show me your login page's code?

Comment: This answer is wrong. The question is using @vite, not mix. To fix this, you can find a complete guide on installing Tailwind in Laravel using vite: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/laravel

Comment: I added this to guest.blade.php and that fixed the registration page and to app.blade.php and that fixed the dashboard page.
However, at the top of the pages in the browser you see a log message:
@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
Since this is the first time I try using Laravel I have no idea if this is to be expected

Comment: Not sure what to say here as the context is not clear but this might be due to Development build. Could probably be solved with production build.